# Extract elements from List within RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have an RDD of the form

```
RDD[(String, String, String)]
```

I'm applying a function that extracts data from the third element and creates an RDD of the form

```
RDD[(String, String, List[String])]
```

I'd like to produce a final RDD where each element of the List is mapped against the first two elements. Something like,

```
RDD[(String, String, String)] = RDD[(String, String, List[String])].map(case(x, y, z) => (x, y, z._1), (x, y, z._2), ....))
```

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Give an example of input and output. The .... is not very helpful. Also, z is in your example a list of String, so can't have a _1, _2 to access members. Do you just want the first two elements along with every element of the List[String]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this should do what you're looking for

```
val newRDD = listRDD.flatMap{case(x, y, z) => z.map((x,y,_))}
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems you are looking for flatMap or flatMapValues (depending on your transformation):

```
def flatMap[U](f: (T) ⇒ TraversableOnce[U])(implicit arg0: ClassTag[U]): RDD[U]
```

[flatMap](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD): Return a new RDD by first applying a function to all elements of this RDD, and then flattening the results.

```
def flatMapValues[U](f: (V) ⇒ TraversableOnce[U]): RDD[(K, U)]
```

[flatMapValues](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions): Pass each value in the key-value pair RDD through a flatMap function without changing the keys; this also retains the original RDD's partitioning.

Comment: That's not an answer to the question. It might make a good comment, though

Comment: @Paul It does to the level of detail given in the question. The suggested functions allow to make the "generic" transformation required by the question.

Comment: Then the response is to ask for clarification, I think, not to give some generic answer about flatMap.

Comment: Why? Things can be solved at different levels of abstraction. If someone wants a generic way to solve a problem, a generic answer may suffice. This is something the asker decide (when his problem is solved). But if the asker wants another level of detail, I'm happy to provide it or to delete the answer.

Comment: Whatever, I have my opinion, you have yours.